# Geocoding out of Salesforce.com (large number of static adresses)

Tags: salesforce, geocoding

We have developed an application in [Salesforce.com](http://Salesforce.com) to geocode and display `account information (address information)` on `Google Maps` within `Salesforce.com`. We have around 750k addresses for the initial (one-time) geocoding process (static address data), as we store the `lat/lon` with the account.
Is their any way to get this geocoded done in one 'batch' as we seem to hit the daily allowance of request per day (3k)?
Thanks for your support and feedback.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to use Google to do this and you need to precompute the lat/lon coordinates, you'll need to upgrade to the [Google Maps API for Business](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-compare.html). The table on that link provides a detailed overview of the limit differences, and I suspect that the terms of use may also be more in line with what you're developing too.

If your goal is to create a Google Map from the addresses, you may also consider just passing the address data instead of the latitude and longitude. Their static maps will work fine as long as you know which locations that you'd like to use on the map, you don't have too many locations in one map and you don't need interactivity. Otherwise, you should use the javascript API and their documentation is very good for that.

If you don't know which locations you'd like to use on the map, you could use the lat/lon coordinates of their zip codes (which are [freely available](http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/)) to create a view port.

If you'd like a static map of the locations (whether or not you precompute the lat/lon), I'd recommend taking a look at the [apexgooglestaticmap Github repository](https://github.com/seandevine/apexgooglestaticmap). It makes it quite easy to make certain types of static Google maps in APEX and VisualForce. Here's an example from that README:

**APEX Controller**

```
String[] homes = new String[]{'Albany, NY','Wellesley, MA','New York, NY','Pittsburgh, PA','01945','Ann Arbor, MI','Chicago, IL'};
GoogleStaticMap.MapPath moves = new GoogleStaticMap.MapPath(homes).color('0x000000ff');
String movesUrl = new GoogleStaticMap().addPath(moves).url;
```

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:image value="{!movesUrl}">
```

**Google Maps URL and Image**

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=500x350&markers=label:0%7CAlbany%2C+NY&markers=label:1%7CWellesley%2C+MA&markers=label:2%7CNew+York%2C+NY&markers=label:3%7CPittsburgh%2C+PA&markers=label:4%7C01945&markers=label:5%7CAnn+Arbor%2C+MI&markers=label:6%7CChicago%2C+IL&markers=label:0%7CAlbany%2C+NY&markers=label:1%7CWellesley%2C+MA&markers=label:2%7CNew+York%2C+NY&markers=label:3%7CPittsburgh%2C+PA&markers=label:4%7C01945&markers=label:5%7CAnn+Arbor%2C+MI&markers=label:6%7CChicago%2C+IL&path=weight:5%7Ccolor:0x000000ff%7CAlbany%2C+NY%7CWellesley%2C+MA%7CNew+York%2C+NY%7CPittsburgh%2C+PA%7C01945%7CAnn+Arbor%2C+MI%7CChicago%2C+IL&
```

[image: Google Maps Example]

There are also [many other geocoding APIs available](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=geocode+api&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). They each have their own terms of service, so make sure that your application matches the acceptable uses before you build anything with them. I've personally used [PCMiler Web Services](http://www.alk.com/) with success, and [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) for reverse geocoding (they have a number of other great features too).

Answer (score 0):

Google only allows that max per IP Address.  If you were able to maximize the locations you were doing them from, max out at work, home or maybe your local starbucks, you could be able to hit the goal easily.  If you have more than 250 employees just assign the 'homework' of going home and geocoding it!  Spread the wealth, and the fun, of geocoding!

The other solution is using Google Maps API For Business, which allows you to do a max of 100,000 requests per day.  For more information look at: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/ ; for more information specifically on Geoogle Maps API For Business: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/business/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I use this [geocoder](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder), and add my list and use yahoo to get the `lat` and `long`.

We have `FindNearby` installed, so once I get all the addresses geo-coded, I add them back into my excel worksheet in the respective column that has the `Record ID`. Since we use `FindNearby`, I have to add a column that is titled `Mapping Status`, and all cells under this say Located. I used ApexData loader to mass upload into SF. Note, geocoder has a limit of only 1000 records at a single "code" click, but it has no limit of how many lists you can process per day.

Answer (score -1):

I changes some code to use Bing map services instead of google. There limits are based on keys and are much larger. Also when the key hits its max requests, then you can just get a new free key and apply it.